# webpack dev server default setting change

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

In default, "dev server" is listening to the file "index.html" in the main direction.

I am using the default configuration, without any additional packages.

How I could change the direction and name of the file?

Comment: Are you using any additional packages? Like React or any other package that comes bundled with webpack? The way to configure this might differ between packages. Please update your question with more specific information.

Comment: Thank's, I changed. I don't use any additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `historyApiFallback` config for this:

```
devServer: {
  ...,
  historyApiFallback: {
    rewrites: [
      { from: /./, to: 'path-to-your-html.html' }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's. I will try. In a property of "from" what need to specify?

Comment: I have tried but didn't change anything whatever is listening to the main direction

Comment: @Makhnov did you restart your dev server?

Comment: Yes. I fixed but use another the property "index". historyApiFallback: {
       index: 'panel/index.html' 
  }. How could I change the extension of a file from HTML on the PHP ?